# Run a series of tasks, but depending on progress start on task x in bash (continue switch case)

Tags: bash, switch-statement, progress

I have a series of tasks that run one after the other, but depending on the progress, that is saved in a variable it has to start at the appropriate step.

For instance, I have 5 tasks. Task 1 is supposed to start, followed by task 2, then task 3 and so on. But if the variable progress contains the value 2, it should start at task 2, continue with task 3 and so on.

I thought this would be achievable with a switch case, like:

```
case $progress in
    1)
        echo "Task1"
        $progress=2;;
    2)
        echo "Task2"
        $progress=3;;
    3)
        echo "Task3";;
    *)
        echo "null";;
esac
```

The problem here is that the switch case ends, after the first match. How do I have the switch case continue after the first match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [boolean.is.null's own helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35258830/45375), here's an **overview of `case`-branch terminators**:

- **`;;`** *[the only option up to Bash 3.x]*

  - **Exit** the `case` statement right away (from a matching branch).
- **`;&`** *[Bash 4.0+]*

  - ***Unconditionally* fall through to the *next* branch** - as in a C `switch` statement's `case` handler without `break`. Note that unconditional means that the very next branch is entered, no matter what its condition is.
- **`;;&`** *[Bash 4.0+]*

  - ***Continue evaluating* branch conditions** until another one, if any (including `*)`), matches.

`;;` example; outputs line `one`:

```
case 1 in
  1)  # entered, because it matches and is the first condition
    echo 'one'
    ;;  # exits the `case` statement here
  ?)  # never entered
    echo 'any single char.'
    ;;
esac
```

`;&` example (Bash 4.0+); outputs lines `one` and `two`:

```
case 1 in
  1)  # entered, because it matches and is the first condition
    echo 'one'
    ;&  # fall through to very next branch
  2) # entered, because the previous branch matched and fell through
    echo 'two'
    ;;  # exits the `case` statement here
esac
```

`;;&` example (Bash 4.0+); outputs line `one` and `any`:

```
case 1 in
  1) # entered, because it matches and is the first condition
    echo 'one'
    ;;&  # continue evaluation branch conditions
  2) # not entered, because its condition doesn't match
    echo 'two'
    ;;
  *)  # entered, because it's the next *matching* condition
    echo 'any'
    ;; # using a terminator is optional in the * branch
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that recent bash version offer the `;&` allowing a "falltrough" in the switch case statement. This is exactly what I was looking for.

```
case $progress in
    1)
        echo "Task1"
        $progress=2
        ;&
    2)
        echo "Task2"
        $progress=3
        ;&
    3)
        echo "Task3";;
    *)
        echo "null";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `while` loop and a `break 2` statement in the default case.